# Countdown and bootstrap progress bar "bump"

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, timer

I'm working on a little "web app" for a quiz.
Each slide has got a certain amount of time to be answered (or 0 to infinite time).

I find JS here to do the countdown:

```
        function Countdown(options) {
            var timer,
                    instance = this,
                    seconds = options.seconds || 10,
                    updateStatus = options.onUpdateStatus || function () {},
                    counterEnd = options.onCounterEnd || function () {};

            function decrementCounter() {
                updateStatus(seconds);
                if (seconds === 0) {
                    counterEnd();
                    instance.stop();
                }
                seconds--;
            }

            this.start = function () {
                clearInterval(timer);
                timer = 0;
                seconds = options.seconds;
                timer = setInterval(decrementCounter, 1000);
            };

            this.stop = function () {
                clearInterval(timer);
            };
        }
 var myCounter = new Countdown({
                    seconds: timetogo, // number of seconds to count down
                    onUpdateStatus: function (sec) {
                        elapsed = timetogo - sec;
                        $('.progress-bar').width(((elapsed / timetogo) * 100) + "%");
                    }, // callback for each second
                    onCounterEnd: function () {
                        //alert('counter ended!');
                    } // final action
                });

                myCounter.start();
```

I made a jsfiddle here :

https://jsfiddle.net/mitchum/kz2400cc/2/

But i am having trouble when you go to the next slide, the progress bar "bump".
after looking into "live source panel from chrome" I saw it's like the first "counter" is not stopped and still runs.

Do you have any tips or hint to help me to solve my bug ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must pay attention to the scope of the variables. I change the "var myCounter" under document ready in "var myCounterFirst". [Check the updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kz2400cc/3/).

```
  var timetogoFirst = $('.current').attr("data-time");
  var myCounterFirst = new Countdown({
    seconds: timetogoFirst, // number of seconds to count down
    onUpdateStatus: function (sec) {
      elapsed = timetogoFirst - sec;
      $('.progress-bar').width(((elapsed / timetogoFirst) * 100) + "%");
    }, // callback for each second
    onCounterEnd: function () {
      alert('counter ended!');
    } // final action
  });
  myCounterFirst.start();
```

Comment: Thanks for your update but I still see the same "bump" effect on your fiddle

Comment: I'm sorry ! you are right !! Probably I'm tired ... I understand a whole other thing. I try to solve, otherwise delete the wrong solution :)

Comment: You help me I think to "solve" the issue...

https://jsfiddle.net/mitchum/kz2400cc/4/

I just add a trigger in "onUpdateStatus" like if we change of slide, it's stop the counter and it's seem to work !!!

Comment: Well, the important thing was to solve :) Good work !